# После выключения через 5-7 секунд снова включается ноутбук

Tags: ubuntu

Доброго времени суток. Есть такая проблемка, купил ноутбук Acer v5 571G, установил ubuntu 12.04, всё отлично не считая Вай фай, но это пол беды, что больше всего раздражает, так это то что после отключения компьютера он сам через 5-7 секунд снова включается. Поставил windows 7 такой проблемы не наблюдается,переустановил на Fedora 17 вновь появилась... Что может быть? Может кто сталкивался?! (мамка с EFi)

Answer (score 1):

Я подозреваю, что ноут просыпается либо из-за wake-on-lan, который включен в биосе, либо кнопка включения западает (было такое как раз на новых ноутах да и на некоторых системниках тоже).

wake-on-lan можно попробовать отключить в биосе.

А кнопку можно попробовать разработать, многократно нажимая на неё (с отключённой батареей, дабы ноут не включался).