# Ubuntu сразу выходит из режима ожидания

Tags: ubuntu

Стоит Ubuntu 20.04. Бесит то, что нормально не работает режим ожидания. Он срабатывает, моник выключается, но через 2 секунды снова появляется изображение. И так по кругу бесконечно. Как это лечить и в какую сторону копать?

**Upd:** До этого была 18.04, там проблемы не было. На винде тоже проблемы нет

**Upd2:** `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep enabled` говорит такое:

```
GP17      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:07.1
XHC0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:09:00.3
GP18      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:08.1
PS2K      S3    *enabled   pnp:00:03
GPP2      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:01.3
PTXH      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:01:00.0
```

Comment: возможные дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/343866/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/721084/178576)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin один вопрос про гибернацию, второй про выключение, режим ожидания это совсем другое...

Comment: я пользуюсь xubuntu потому что не люблю гном и тут с этим постоянно какая-то беда. от версии к версии они что-то меняют. не знаю как конкретно в ubuntu, скорее всего так же. мне однажды всё это надоело и я просто удалил все пакеты, которые отвечают за автоматическое управление питанием. уточните, у вас только при автоматическом переходе этот глюк или вручную тоже?

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf вручную тоже

Comment: А что говорит `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep enabled` ?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy добавил

Comment: Попробуйте запретить PTXH. Только бэкапами обвешайтесь всякими.

Comment: Общий рецепт: берите сокращение из списка и ищите вроде `"PTXH" ubuntu`. Много интересно можно найти.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Что такое "PTXH"? Я пытался загуглить `PTXH ubuntu` вообще никакой информации нет

Comment: ["PTXH" ubuntu](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=%22PTXH%22+ubuntu) - первая ссылка.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy да, я тоже нашёл это и попробовал, не помогло. Но я так и не понял что такое PTXH и как оно влияет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121046/discussion-between-stanislav-volodarskiy-and-inventor).